# Node js Mysql operand should contain 1 column(s) insert

Tags: mysql, node.js

I take data and push it in empty arrays. Then I want to send it to the DB but I made some mistake that cant solve. 
Here is error message : **operand should contain 1 column(s)**

Here is the code :

```
 let sql = "INSERT INTO models (name, url) VALUES(?, ?) ";
    cn.query(sql, [proname, innerURL], function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      cn.query(
        "DELETE n1 FROM models n1, models n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name AND n1.url = n2.url"
      );
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the raw insert query generate by node with parameter values ?

Comment: I am new to it and I dont realy understand what it means. How can I do it?

Comment: Something like [Node.js/MySQL: Printing actual query in error log in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169797/node-js-mysql-printing-actual-query-in-error-log-in-node-js)