# Nested queries do not work in Node.js & MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My code is below.

The error I am getting is in a query statement that contains an UPDATE statement.

Why do I get an `ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com'' at line 1`?

**controller**

```
...

exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const secretKey = req.app.get('jwt-secret');

  let sql = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?`;

  User.query(sql, [email], (err, result) => {
    ...
    if (result[0] === undefined || result[0].password !== encrypted) {
      res.status(300).send('ID, PS check plz');
    } else {
      const token = jwtSign(secretKey, result[0].userId, email);

      sql = `UPDATE user SET token = ? WHERE email = ?`;

      User.query(sql, [token, email], (err, result) => {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        ...
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Is `token` value blank?

Comment: @Samir There is token in console.log(token) in the nested query but empty in the query results

Comment: What is a result of `console.log(typeof token);`?

Comment: @y15e Token type is String (JWT)

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the `token` value. Can you `console.log` you query as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169797/node-js-mysql-printing-actual-query-in-error-log-in-node-js